# AMCharts - CSV export using different data source other than data used for chart creation

Tags: csv, export, amcharts

We are creating AMchart using data source say data1 and we want to export data from another data source say data2. Tried various methods to export the data with data2 in CSV format without affecting the chart that is plotted.
In our code, we are not using explicitly assigning chart.data to plot the chart. But when we assign the chart.data with another source for exporting the data. The plotted chart is getting disposed.

Is there a way to export the chart data in CSV format from a different data source without affecting the plotted chart ?

Tried to assign the exported data using chart.exporting.data but it doesn't have any effect on export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the functionality using an adapter.
Here, the chart is using one data source and exported using another data source.

```
chart.exporting.adapter.add('data', (data => {
                    data.data = [];
                    data.data = exportData;
                    return data;
                }));
```

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

/* Create chart instance */
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

/* Add data */
chart.data = [{
  "year": "1994",
  "cars": 1587,
  "motorcycles": 650,
  "bicycles": 121
}, {
  "year": "1995",
  "cars": 1567,
  "motorcycles": 683,
  "bicycles": 146
}, {
  "year": "1996",
  "cars": 1617,
  "motorcycles": 691,
  "bicycles": 138
}, {
  "year": "1997",
  "cars": 1630.0,
  "motorcycles": 642,
  "bicycles": 127
}, {
  "year": "1998",
  "cars": 1660,
  "motorcycles": 699,
  "bicycles": 105
}, {
  "year": "1999",
  "cars": 1683,
  "motorcycles": 721,
  "bicycles": 109
}, {
  "year": "2000",
  "cars": 1691,
  "motorcycles": 737,
  "bicycles": 112
}, {
  "year": "2001",
  "cars": 1298,
  "motorcycles": 680,
  "bicycles": 101
}, {
  "year": "2002",
  "cars": 1275,
  "motorcycles": 664,
  "bicycles": 97
}, {
  "year": "2003",
  "cars": 1246,
  "motorcycles": 648,
  "bicycles": 93
}, {
  "year": "2004",
  "cars": 1218,
  "motorcycles": 637.9,
  "bicycles": 101
}, {
  "year": "2005",
  "cars": 1213,
  "motorcycles": 633,
  "bicycles": 87
}, {
  "year": "2006",
  "cars": 1199,
  "motorcycles": 621,
  "bicycles": 79
}, {
  "year": "2007",
  "cars": 1110,
  "motorcycles": 210,
  "bicycles": 81
}, {
  "year": "2008",
  "cars": 1165,
  "motorcycles": 232,
  "bicycles": 75
}, {
  "year": "2009",
  "cars": 1145,
  "motorcycles": 219,
  "bicycles": 88
}, {
  "year": "2010",
  "cars": 1163.8,
  "motorcycles": 201,
  "bicycles": 82
}, {
  "year": "2011",
  "cars": 1180,
  "motorcycles": 285,
  "bicycles": 87
}, {
  "year": "2012",
  "cars": 1159,
  "motorcycles": 277,
  "bicycles": 71
}];

/* Create axes */
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";

/* Create value axis */
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
 valueAxis.numberFormatter.numberFormat = {
  "style": "decimal",
  "minimumFractionDigits": 0
};  

/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "cars";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
series1.name = "Cars";
series1.strokeWidth = 3;
series1.tensionX = 0.7;
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";


/* Add legend */
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

/* Create a cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

/* Configure axis tooltip */
var axisTooltip = categoryAxis.tooltip;
axisTooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#07BEB8");
axisTooltip.background.strokeWidth = 0;
axisTooltip.background.cornerRadius = 3;
axisTooltip.background.pointerLength = 0;
axisTooltip.dy = 5;

var dropShadow = new am4core.DropShadowFilter();
dropShadow.dy = 1;
dropShadow.dx = 1;
dropShadow.opacity = 0.5;
axisTooltip.filters.push(dropShadow);



let exportData = [{
 "year": "2000",
 "car": "BMW"
  
},
{
 "year": "2001",
 "car": "Audi"
  
}];


chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();

chart.exporting.adapter.add('data', (data => {
                    data.data = [];
                    data.data = exportData;
                    return data;
                }));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```